# Remove unecessary layout symbol from expression

Tags: rascal

I am trying to achieve this in rascal :

```
select   a from     myTable; => select a from myTable
```

Basically I just want to remove the unnecessary Layout of expression and also the commentaries in order to get the minimal form of my expression.

How can I achieve that in Rascal ?

Comment: did my answer work Jérôme?

Comment: Yep it works :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can replace a specific parse tree node with itself with a visit `=>`, and substitute the children back. In the example below, only the spaces around the `+` are replaced then
2. You can replace all Layout in one go, by visiting the tree and matching on the Layout non-terminal (could be a different name for your grammar). In the example below, you can also see how that is done.

```
module NormalizeLayout

import demo::lang::Pico::Syntax;
import ParseTree;
import IO;

// a stub space
private Layout space = appl(prod(layouts("Layout"), [], {}), [char(32)]);

void example() {
   t = parse(#start[Program], 
     "begin
     '  declare 
     '    a : natural;
     '
     '    a := 1 +
     '         1
     'end");

   t = visit (t) {

   // this one sets the spaces only of a very specific rule, namely + expressions:
      case (Expression) `<Expression l> + <Expression r>` 
        => (Expression) `<Expression l> + <Expression r>`

   // as an alternative here we match all layout in the entire program and replace it     
     case Layout _ => space
   }

   println(t); //  begin declare a : natural ; a := 1 + 1 end 
}
```

The main difficulty lies in obtaining an example parse tree for a space since the `(NT)` and the `[NT]` notation do not support parsing directly from a layout non-terminal. So in this example I jumped to the generic level and invented a parse tree for Layouts (see `ParseTree` module for how parse trees are defined under-the-hood in Rascal).

Another (type-safe) trick for obtaining such an example tree is getting one from an example like so:

```
private Layout space() {
  visit ((Expression) `1 + 1`) {
    case Layout x : return x;
  }

  fail;
}
```